# Функция, приводящая строку к целому число, которая выбрасывает исключение

Tags: c++, исключения

Какая есть в С++ функция, которая приводит строку к целому числу и выбрасывает исключение если преобразование не удалось? atoi ничего не выбрасывает.

Comment: Посмотрите, например, `stoi` - она говорит, где заканчивается преобразованное число, а уж навесить исключение после проверки - легко.

Comment: `boost::lexical_cast`, однако это очень толерантная функция, которая конвертирует аналогично потокам (может игнорировать пробелы и т.п.).

Comment: что значит "не удалось"? К примеру, если строка содержит: `"10 "`, то следует исключение выбросить? (строка не только цифры содержит)

Comment: Довольно легко можно самому написать такую функцию. И при ошибке преобразования выбрасывать исключение. Всего то нужен цикл перебора символов строки и switch внутри цикла.

Comment: Вот тут все это есть с пояснениями:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4442658/c-parse-int-from-string

Answer (score 1):

### Вам нужна функция [std::stoi](https://ru.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stol)

Функция пытается сконвертировать строку в int, если не получилось - выкидывает исключение [std::invalid_argument](https://ru.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/invalid_argument).

Преобразование считается неудавшимся, если после отрезания максимального количества пробелов в начале строки строка будет начинаться не на цифру, и не на пару "-" плюс цифра, и не на пару "+" плюс цифра (то есть допустимые варианты начала - любая цифра, или знак минуса и хотя бы одна цифра, или знак плюса и хотя бы одна цифра).

Корректно сконвертируются, например, следующие строки: `"42", "+42", "-42", "  42", "  -42", "42aaa", "-42 42"`.

Не сконвертируются (и выбросят исключения), следующие строки: `"a42", "- 42", "  42", "  -a42", "a42aaa"`.

Ссылка для экспериментов: [ссылка](http://cpp.sh/8smp4)

Код:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <stdexcept>

int main()
{
    try
    {
        std::string test = "- 42";
        int myint = stoi(test);
        std::cout << myint << '\n';
    }
    catch (std::exception &e)
    {
        std::cout << "Exception catched : " << e.what() << std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```